# understanding pytorch sample code for gradient calculation

Tags: python, pytorch, gradient

I do not understand the purpose of the following line of code:

```
external_grad = torch.tensor([1., 1.])
Q.backward(gradient=external_grad)
```

Here's the complete program from https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/autograd_tutorial.html

```
import torch
import numpy as np
#
a = torch.tensor([2., 3.], requires_grad=True)
b = torch.tensor([6., 4.], requires_grad=True)
Q = 3* a**3 - b**2
#
print('a ',a)
print('---------------------')
print('b ',b)
print('---------------------')
print('Q ',Q)
print('---------------------')
#
# Q.backward()
#print(a.grad) results in 'grad can be implicitly created only for scalar outputs'
#print(b.grad) ditto
# because the tensor a, b contain more than 1 element
# https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/loss-backward-raises-error-grad-can-be-implicitly-created-only-for-scalar-outputs/12152
# pytorch doc : https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/autograd_tutorial.html
#
external_grad = torch.tensor([1., 1.])
Q.backward(gradient=external_grad)
print(a.grad)
print(b.grad)
```

The ouptut is:

```
a  tensor([2., 3.], requires_grad=True)
---------------------
b  tensor([6., 4.], requires_grad=True)
---------------------
Q  tensor([-12.,  65.], grad_fn=<SubBackward0>)
---------------------
tensor([36., 81.])
tensor([-12.,  -8.])
```

which matches dq/da and dq/db at the grid points I defined, but how does it work? Also, failing to provide:

> gradient=external_grad

results in the exception shown as a comment in the code

Comment: What is your question exactly? What does `external_grad` represent for *autograd*?

Comment: this blog  https://towardsdatascience.com/pytorch-autograd-understanding-the-heart-of-pytorchs-magic-2686cd94ec95 explains it better than the PyTorch guide -- see example where they calculate dz/dx where x  and y are [1,3] tensors and z= x*y